# How do you add extra topology in Blender?

Tags: modeling

In the following video :

[Making a 3D Clownfish in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/T5YfWoE_yTk&t=15s)

how was the extra topology added? The part where he says adding in some topology around the 15-seconds mark.

Comment: hello, what part of the video are you talking about? Maybe show a screenshot?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: the part where he says adding in some topology around 15 seconds mark : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5YfWoE_yTk&t=15s

Comment: if you are talking about the additional loopcuts it's Ctrl R and MMB or + or - of numpad keys

Comment: (The main link in your post is broken, for me) .. The other tool used, (just below the dorsal fin,) is the `K` topology Knife tool.  If we've managed to help you in the commentary. maybe this post doesn't quite stand up as a question for the archive, and can be closed out? Please let us know how you're doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At 15 s he is doing a loopcut operation, put your mouse cursor on the edge you want to subdivide and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>MMB</kbd> or numpad <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> to add or subtract edge loops. It adds edge loop around the object, as long as it is made of quads:

[image]